# How NOT to execute a script by double-clicking on a cell or pressing F2

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

The shown procedure is for an existing input mask that I am not allowed to change. I am able to collect several data from different cells by formula but the user must be able to input numbers without affecting this formulas. I am really new to VBA but the users are (not willing) or not able to understand simple excel procedures at all.

This script stores the content of a cell by selection.

By worksheet change (the cell gets a new input) the formula in cell will be divided in a left part before the closing parenthese as String and in a right part as a value (Long). The result is the formula (left Part) and the Value (right part) plus the input in the selected (initial) cell.

The formulas contain references to other cells and sum values e.g. `=WENNFEHLER(AUFRUNDEN(C376/$M$369+P509;0);0)+0` the formula here in the example is for illustration only

Genearally this works great but my Error handling seems to be a mess. Also my code is very simple for me to understand it, but is it optimal?

The script must NOT:

- <strike>being activated when the user doubleclick a cell or pressing F2 on keyboard (<- probably not an error but a main issue to avoid unintentional input)</strike> seems to be solved `If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Or Target.HasFormula And Target.Formula = OldValues(1) Then Exit Sub`could made my day... <strike>but when I have a cell with Value and no Formula it cause a problem when I count e.g. 6+6 :(</strike> <- solved
- <strike>run when more than 1 cell is selcted</strike> <-solved
- <strike>run when clicking left top corner of the sheet or pressing Strg+A on keyboard to select all cells (<- main issue)</strike> <- solved
- <strike>run when shapes, buttons or something changes</strike> <- seems to be impossible so it is solved

I tried to include `On Error Goto ...` but I made Excel crashing with it so some help would be verry welcome.

after any changes the script runs great and looks like follows:

```
Dim OldValues As New Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.CountLarge = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9:C853")) Is Nothing Then
        Set OldValues = Nothing
        OldValues.Add Target.Formula
        Debug.Print OldValues(1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Or Target.HasFormula And Target.Formula = OldValues(1) Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, ValInput As Long, ValShortFormula As String, ValFormulaEnd As Long
    Dim keyCells As Range: Set keyCells = Range("C9:C853")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set keyCells = Application.Union(keyCells.Precedents, keyCells)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, keyCells) Is Nothing Then
            r = Target.Row
            c = Target.Column
            ValInput = Target.Value
            ValShortFormula = Left(OldValues(1), InStrRev(OldValues(1), ")") - 0)
            ValFormulaEnd = Right(OldValues(1), Len(OldValues(1)) - InStrRev(OldValues(1), ")"))
            Debug.Print OldValues(1)
            Debug.Print ValInput
            Debug.Print ValShortFormula
            Debug.Print ValFormulaEnd
                    Cells(r, c).Formula = ValShortFormula & "+" & ValFormulaEnd + ValInput
                    Set OldValues = Nothing
                    OldValues.Add Target.Formula
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But I am sure there is a lot space of improvement, I would apreciate some hints :)

[image: example setup]

<strike>The execution of the script is probably triggered by the recognition as input. I haven't found any hints how to compare this action with a real input (positive or negative number), it probably won't help to compare values because it will get an identical result.</strike>

<strike>The Overflow error may come from storing all cells to a collection? How to deal with this? I thought about variables defined differently, but again have not found a solution.</strike>

Hopefully the description is understandable and sufficiently extensive
Thx in advance :)

Comment: You can use sheet event ``BeforeDoubleClick``. See https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.beforedoubleclick

Comment: `Target` is always a range, so you will not need to test for `TypeName(Target) <> "Range"`

Comment: `If Target.CountLarge > 1` should fix the overflow problem.  `Target.Count` can't handle the case where the whole sheet is selected.   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge

Comment: You don't need `For Each cell In Target` if you're only responding to single-cell values of `Target`

Comment: Thanks a lot folks!
@ValNik -> `BeforeDoublecClick` is an good idea but i found a smarter way (for me) with less effort `If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Or Target.HasFormula And Target.Formula = OldValues(1) Then Exit Sub` solves the overflow error (Thx @Tim Williams) and quits the macro only when a formula is detected equal to the collection value.